# Cakephp hasMany and HABTM in one model

Tags: php, cakephp

I have HABTM and hasMany in one model like below:

```
var $hasMany = array(
        'Interestsub' => array(
            'className' => 'Interestsub',
            'foreignKey' => 'interest_id',
            'dependant' => true
        )
    );

    var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'User' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'joinTable' => 'interests_users',
            'foreignKey' => 'interest_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'user_id',
            'unique' => true,
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'deleteQuery' => '',
            'insertQuery' => ''
        )
    );
```

The problem is when I do a find query with recursive 3 in User model it only gives me Interest and Interest_User model data but not Interestsub which is hasMany table.

Is there a way to get this with my find query so it is nested inside Interest?

Comment: what is recursive 3?^^ http://book.cakephp.org/view/1063/recursive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try recursive 2, or better yet, the containable behavior.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html